# how to give sharing option to the grid images

Tags: java, android, image, sharing

i am creating an application which i want share images to any social platform.
i used a grid view successfully, which shows all the images and can be viewed in specific full image activity to show the user selected image.
i want to add a social share function to the applications which get the image location and share to the social platform.

Here is my **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.jai.desimeme;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
            // passing array index
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}




}
```

with my **activity_main.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/grid_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
android:numColumns="4"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="5dp" >

</GridView>
```

i used the **FullImageActivity.java** for the preview of image selected //here i want to add the sharing link.

```
package com.jai.desimeme;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;

@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
}



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String fileName = "test.png";
        File dest = new File(sd, fileName);
        try {
            FileOutputStream out;
            out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item:
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(dest);
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.share)));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

for above code i used this **full_image.xml** activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
<ImageView android:id="@+id/full_image_view" 
android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="100dp"
android:src="@drawable/image_border"
style="@style/myImageView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

in here i created **ImageAdapter.java** to store the image files.

```
package com.jai.desimeme;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {

        R.drawable.rage_0001,
        ...
        R.drawable.rage_178,



};

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    return imageView;
}

}
```

and here is my **AndroidManifest.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jai.desimeme"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.1.3" android:installLocation="auto">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:permission="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
    <activity
        android:name="com.jai.desimeme.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- FullImageActivity -->
    <activity android:name=".FullImageActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".About" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">  </activity>
</application>
```

guide me how to add sharing link to this application, i tried so many ways but end up in errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this on any click event of your UI element.

```
BitmapDrawable bm = (BitmapDrawable) yourImageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap mysharebmp = bm.getBitmap();
String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                    mysharebmp, "MyImage", null);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,
                    "Share image using"));
```