# Giving share option to the grid images

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio, sharing

i am creating an application which i want share images to any social platform. i used a grid view successfully . i want to add a social share function to the applications which get the image location and share to the social platform. i tried this method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21848647/4294399

```
BitmapDrawable bm = (BitmapDrawable) yourImageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap mysharebmp = bm.getBitmap();
 String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                mysharebmp, "MyImage", null);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("image/png");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,
                "Share image using"));
```

it's giving fatal error how can i share image when the click from gridView ? I'm getting

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.widget.ImageView.getDrawable()' on a null object reference`` i'm getting this error

```
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new FoodListAdapter(this, R.layout.food_items, list);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // get all data from sqlite
    Cursor cursor = MainActivity.sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM FOOD");
    list.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        String price = cursor.getString(2);
        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(3);

        list.add(new Food(name, price, image, id));
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                
        }
    });
    @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if(requestCode == 888){
        if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 888);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You don't have permission to access file location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return;
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == 888 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            imageViewFood.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: could you please add the stacktrace from the logcat so I can know where is the error coming from?

Comment: and are you getting the null pointer exception when click some button?

Comment: i fixed with recyclerview

Comment: Then please share your answer and accept your own answer as the correct one :)\

Answer (score -1):

Call startActivity inside onItemClickListener. You will have to insert the logic that gets the location of Image inside the clickListener, attach that path as extra to the intent.

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.widget.ImageView.getDrawable()' on a null object reference`` i'm getting this error

Comment: please update the code in the question with new code so I can know what you did. Cheers!!